# How to say "this way" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice

How to say "this way" in Japanese?

I know の様に which means "such as something" (子供の様に "like a child"), and also この様 "such" (この様なホテル "such hotel").

But I would like to know how to say "this way", for instance "we don't say it this way". I suppose it is この方, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Literally, *we don't say it this way* translates to

- このようには言わない
- こういう風{ふう}には言わない

Both are fine, but I think it is more common to use

- こういう言い方{かた}はしない

which literally means *We don't do this way of saying (it)*.

Note that if you are pointing out error/unnaturalness in conversation (referring to the interlocutor's expresion), そういう言い方 would be appropriate.

---

Other uses of *this way* require different translations.

- This way, please. こちらへどうぞ
- Go this way. この道を行きなさい.

Comment: You might also hear こんなに, which has a similar meaning.